# Sorting Elements of a List by Characteristics of Those Elements

Tags: r, sorting, analytics

Suppose I have a list of tables. One of the columns of each of the tables is named  and contains a count of NA values. For example, object 'e' in the below example shows a frequency of 2 in its last column:

```
a <- seq(1:5)
b <- c(NA,1,2,4,NA) 
c <- a %>% data.frame(.,b)
d <- table(c[1], useNA = "always")
e <- table(c[2], useNA = "always")
f <- list(d, e)
```

Is there a way to order the elements in the list based on the number of NAs in the NA column found in each table in the list? For example, in list f in the above, the NA column in element [1] (i.e. table d) indicates 0 NAs and the NA column in element [2] (i.e. table e) indicates 2 NAs. Since 2 > 0 an I would like to sort the elements of the list from most NAs to least NAs, the list would be reordered to list(e,d).

Comment: This question was very hard to understand. I've improved the spelling and formatting where possible. I also removed irrelevant comments. However, I don't understand the meaning of all of the dashes (`----`) or what you mean by "Right now I'm just using a dumb bubble sort which is easy to customize but it kind of hurts and I expect to find the same kind of issue further on." Can you please clarify your comments and edit your question to abide this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The dashes were just there to mimick what one would see outputed to the console.

Comment: OK, but not in R I think. That was part of why I was confused. I'll replace those with spaces for you if you'll read the linked resource.

Comment: I realize it is hard to understand because it is quite convoluted. What I mean if we forget this context is just "how to sort a list according to a comparison which I can implement, In this case that would according to elements in sublist.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @Hack-R ok thanks for the edit. Why the downvote though? I feel like this has to be frequently encountered, and very counter intuitive in R for anybody coming from a C style language

Comment: The question is terribly worded but it is an interesting problem. I have proposed a rewrite of the entire question. Essentially, SolipsistElvis is trying to order the elements of a list of tables by a comparison of each of the tables on the value of a commonly named column of each table.

Comment: The example could be simplified a lot more yet - e.g. - `a <- table(c(1:5,NA),useNA="always"); b <- table(c(1,2,4,NA,NA),useNA="always"); L <- list(a,b)` , which should be re-sorted as a result like `list(b,a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description, we can loop over the elements of the `list` ('f'), subset the elements with NA as names, `order` it decreasingly and use that index to reorder the 'f'.

```
f1 <- f[order(-sapply(f, function(x) x[is.na(names(x))]))]
identical(f1, list(e,d))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, does this mean most of the things one would do in a C style language with overloading and classes definitions is done with functional style programming and, in this case, logical indexing, in R?

Comment: @SolipsistElvis  In `R`, many functions are vectorized, so the code writing part is easier.